# Avalara tax calculation

Tags: node.js, avalara

I'm new to avalara tax calculation, I have few questions
Do I need to create customer every time a new person came to buy that is call createCustomer for tax calculation?
If customer A total amount is 100 so first do I have to create customer A in avalara?
IF no ,how can I get customer Code to pass in createTransaction?
Is there any option where I just pass shipFrom and shipTo and can get tax value based on totalAmount?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is no, however there are some scenarios that you may want to consider for customers that you eventually develop a relationship with.

The customer code is a *required field* when using the AvaTax service as it is the keystone for managing exemption certificates in our service.

You could, during the [CreateTransaction](https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/avatax/rest/v2/methods/Transactions/CreateTransaction/) process for example, use data provided by the customer, or auto generate a CustomerCode (i.e. *Globally Unique Identifier*) to use in the CreateTransaction API.

If the customer requests an exemption later in the relationship, the CustomerCode that was generated in initial transaction could be used later to [CreateCustomer](https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/avatax/rest/v2/methods/Customers/CreateCustomers/) API and subsequently link it to an exemption certificate using [CreateCertificates](https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/avatax/rest/v2/methods/Certificates/CreateCertificates/) API.

During future interactions with the customer using that CustomerCode, AvaTax will search for this value and identify any certificates that are linked to it.

Please visit  https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/ for more details.

You can also interact with other AvaTax developers on [Avalara's Developer Community](https://developercommunity.avalara.com) page.